# Azure API Management Virtual Network - outbound IP and routing

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I have an Azure API Management configured in "Internal" mode with a Virtual Network.
When my API Management calls a backend on the web (i.e. httpbin.org for testing purposes), the Public IP address provided by APIM to this endpoint is the one associated with the APIM instance. Ok with this behavior.

But when I associated a UDR with my Subnet, I want APIM to go out with the IP address of my Network Virtual Appliance and thus use the public Ip address of it instead of the IP address of the APIM instance.

The documentation states that when APIM sends a request to a public-facing endpoint, it always uses its own public IP address as the origin IP.
What I'm looking for is the ability to filter the outbound traffic of APIM thanks to my Network Virtual Appliance but it looks like this is something that is not possible as APIM is going outside without going through the appliance.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by either defining default route via UDR to force all traffic through you NVA. Or by using custom DNS server inside VNET and overriding IP address of public endpoint to NVA's IP.

Comment: Does it mean that this is definitively possible to route all outbound traffic to my NVA?
Do you know where I can find a sample of a default route just to test if it works?

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview#default ?